# Media query in jss not responive

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, jss

I am using style props in my react element with @media query. But for some reason it isn't responding. I am using JSS. Here is my code

```
const style = {
    usernameConatiner: {
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "red"
    },  
    "@media screen and minWidth(32em)": {
        usernameConatiner: {
            backgroundColor: "blue"
        }
     }
}
```

There is obviously a whole bunch of other css rules in the middle. I have also tried to nest the media query which isn't working either.

It is rendered in the following way

```
<div style={styles.usernameConatiner} />
```

Am I missing something very obvious here?

Comment: Shouldn't it need to be something like: `"@media screen and (min-width: 32em)"`?

Comment: In chrome it is giving me an error insupported style property &media screen and min-width(32em)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's happening because your media query is not being defined correctly on the styles object.

The correct media query would be `@media screen and (min-width: 32em)`, notice `min-width: 32em` is inside the parenthesis, and also notice that is written as min-width (separated with a dash) instead of minWidth (camelCase)

Check it working on CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yGEXox

To summarize, your styles object should look like this:

```
const style = {
  usernameContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },  
  '@media screen and (min-width: 32em)': {
    usernameContainer: {
      backgroundColor: "blue"
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

As you already are in JS and want to write a style that depends on width, wouldn't be easier to get the window.width and define your style objects accordingly?

Always remembering you may use `window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateWindowWidth);` to handle the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Two things here.

1. Your `media query` syntax is not correct.
2. You can't use media queries / pseudo selectors like `&:hover, &:disabled` and so on in JSS (CSS in JS) directly. To do this, you must install a thrid party package **Radium** https://www.npmjs.com/package/radium

   Installation - npm install --save radium

**How to use it?**

Once you install radium, your entire app should be enclosed with `<StyleRoot/>` which is a named export from radium. The best place to do this is in index.js.

**index.js**

```
import { StyleRoot } from "radium";

ReactDOM.render(
  <StyleRoot>
    <App />
  </StyleRoot>,

  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

You now need to wrap the component that you are using your media queries in with Radium like this. This can be done for both class and functional components.

**MyComponent.js**

```
import Radium from 'radium'
     
function MyComponent(){

const myStyle = {
 
   color: 'blue',
   backgroundColor : 'red',
   
   // media query

   "@media (max-width: 1100px)": {

      color:'orange',
      backgoundColor : 'black'
     
    }, 

}

return (
  <p style = {myStyle}>Enter your text here</p>
)

}

export default Radium(MyComponent);
```